# Generating a Strongly Symmetric Matrix in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, permutation, symmetric

Any ideas on how to efficiently generate an arbitrary numpy array of fixed dimensions `(n,m)` where all the rows are permutations of each other and all the columns are permutations of each other (i.e. strongly symmetric)?

Comment: Does this matrix need to be equal to its own transposition?

Comment: Nope, the columns and rows can be different from each other - the important thing is that all the rows have the same elements in different orders and the columns idem.

Comment: Is "strongly symmetric" your terminology.  I'm not familiar with it.  This article uses it in a different way https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X14001344.  What you're referring to sounds like a Latin rectangle, but this article defines it somewhat differently https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/latin/latin.pdf.  This question dealt specifically with generating _uniformly_ random Latin squares, which turns out to be tricky https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/generate-random-latin-squares.

Comment: By "arbitrary" did you have a specific distribution in mind?  For fixed dimension `(n,m)` what is your alphabet of symbols?  Do rows and columns need to be distinct permuations?  For a simple case for the dimension `(2,3)`, I believe the only such arrays are constant (all 1's, or all 2's, etc).  I believe that this is true for any `(n,m)` where `n` and `m` are relatively prime to each other. I think I have a proof of that, but I haven't worked it out in detail.

Comment: Thank you @KyleParsons for the comments. 'Strongly Symmetric' is a term I have borrowed from this set of lecture notes http://www.isiweb.ee.ethz.ch/archive/massey_scr/adit1.pdf (see pages 76-78) which describes the transition matrix of a 'strongly symmetric' channel. It is indeed similar to Latin rectangles but not the same. For simplicity, we can restrict the alphabet to be the natural numbers (including 0) and no, I am not looking for any particular distribution, only for some examples of such matrices.

Comment: Also, the columns and rows do not have to be distinct permutations, though they can be distinct (as opposed to in Latin squares).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to generate some such arrays.  Let `a` be the greatest common divisor of `n` and `m`.

1. Split the entire array up into `a` by `a` blocks
2. On each block, generate a latin square (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/generate-random-latin-squares) question for discussion)
3. Randomly permute the rows and columns of the array
4. If desired, perform symbol substitution. That is, if `a` is 3, maybe you turn all the 3's in the grid into 2's.

I'm not sure that this method can generate every possible such grid, but it should be able to generate many of them.  After steps 1 and 2 are complete you'll have a valid array, the remaining steps just add more randomness.

Of course the easiest way to generate such an array is just to fill it will all 1's, but that's not what you're looking for.